Which file to use for the application .env of python or configmap of Kubernetes which is preferable?
I need to separate the configurations from the application and create different configmap of Kubernetes or .env files for different environments, including:

Local
Development
Production

which approach is best using configmap of Kubernetes or .env files and why?
